# Deriving equations for finite domain constraint system

Tags: optimization, compilation, constraints, constraint-programming

The following inequality system is solved for x1 and x2 over the integers.

x1 + x2 = l

x1 >= y1

x2 >= y2

x1 <= z1

x2 <= z2

l - z1 <= x2

l - z2 <= x1

l,y1,y2,z1,z2 are arbitrary but fixed and >= 0.

With the example values

l = 8

y1 = 1

y2 = 2

z1 = z2 = 6

I [solve the system](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x_1+%2B+x_2+%3D+8%2C+x_1+%3E%3D+1%2C+x_2+%3E%3D+2%2C+x_1+%3C%3D+6%2C+x_2+%3C%3D+6%2C+2+%3C%3D+x_2%2C+2+%3C%3D+x_1+) and get the following equations:

2 <= x1 <= 6

x2 = 8 - x1

When I tell WolframAlpha that it should [solve it over the integers](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x_1+%2B+x_2+%3D+8%2C+x_1+%3E%3D+1%2C+x_2+%3E%3D+2%2C+x_1+%3C%3D+6%2C+x_2+%3C%3D+6%2C+2+%3C%3D+x_2%2C+2+%3C%3D+x_1++over+the+integers), it only outputs all possible values.

My question is whether I can derive equations/ranges for x1 and x2 for any given l,y1,y2,z1,z2 programmatically. This problem is related to constraint programming and I found an old paper about this problem: ["Compiling Constraint Solving using Projection"](http://www.cs.washington.edu/research/constraints/solvers/cp97.html) by Harvey et al.

Is this approach used in any modern constraint solving libraries?

The reason I ask this is that I need to solve systems like the above several thousand times with different parameters and this takes a long time if the whole system is read/optimized/solved over and over again. Therefore, if I could compile my parameterized systems once and then just use the compiled versions I expect a massive speed gain.

Comment: Why can't you do it manually? It seems from what you say that your equation system is always the same

Comment: Well, in my use case I need it for arbitrary ones. Otherwise, sure, I could just do it manually.